# Setting background-image to fill entire window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am making a website to practice my web developer skills, (i am still a beginner so be easy on me please). Anyway, i added a background image and i am making it responsive. i am using twitter bootstrap and using the media queries, Everything is working fine, except that when i reduce the web browser's window starting at 595 height x 591 width, the background image starts to not cover the entire window. i want to know why because i am using the media queries, as twitter bootstrap says and i thought the extra small device media query cover this.

I'm really sorry for my bad English, it isn't my first language.

[Here is my website's link.](https://arletcastillo.github.io/OctoAnimals/cyberangel_site/)

If i am not wrong, you can see my HTML and CSS source code my right clicking on the page and clicking on the inspect option, but i am going to add the code here just in case:

```css
body {
  /* background-color: #000000 */
  background-image: url(../images/city_landscape.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
} 

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

/********** Small devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

/********** Extra small devices only **********/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Cyberangel's site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax-utils.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the body doesn't stretch the whole screen, since its content is not big enough.

To solve this, you can try adding `height: 100vh` to your body:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly! Now, if i may ask, what does vh means?

Comment: @cyber_angel `vh` is for *viewport height*, and it indicates the height of the whole screen area. 1vh indicates 1% of the viewport height, so 100vh means "expand the body as much as it fills the screen vertically". Besides `vh`, there is also `vw` which indicates the *viewport width*

Answer (score 0):

To apply an image to the entire page, you need to also give `body` and `html` a height of 100:

```
body, html
{
  height: 100%;
}

.background
{ 
  background-image: url("img_girl.jpg");

  height: 100%; 

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

From: W3Schools

Comment: thanks! Other people answered with a different solution and it fixed the problem but i am going to keep this one in mind too.

Comment: No problem mate

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `background-size: cover` you can use `object-fit: fill;` which will fill entire screen:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    object-fit: fill;
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that this property is not very well [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) by Internet Explorer/Edge browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `height: 100vh;` to the `body` tag will do the trick.

```css
body {
  /* background-color: #000000 */
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1500x800);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}

/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
} 

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

/********** Small devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

/********** Extra small devices only **********/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Cyberangel's site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax-utils.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Somebody answered with this earlier it fixed the problem!

Answer (score -2):

Edit* If you want to dislike, can you also elaborate why?

I would also like to add (and if anyone would like to elaborate) that you can use CSS flexbox and CSS grid which are much easier to understand, that makes Bootstrap obsolete in my opinion, but some say it's still better than grid, still, I'm also just a beginner.

I learn from this as it is really easy to understand:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/